# Seamless/Cylindrical Marquee in GWT

Tags: javascript, jquery, gwt, marquee

here I am again asking for you kind help.

I'm working on a GWT project and trying to add a rolling ticker (marquee) into my page.

Looked into the following options:
a. http://jscroller.markusbordihn.de/ and http://jscroller2.markusbordihn.de/
This is a cool library, but does not seem to work with GWT. I'm not that good with JS, but it appears that this library works on static pages rather than GWT pages, because it assumes that at the time the JS is executed in , the elements to scroll are in the DOM already. Is this incorrect? Has anyone had success with using jscroller(2) with GWT?

b. http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/
Not really tried it, but it seems this should work with GWT. However, this does not seem to support seamless/endless/sylindrical marquee which many people who commented on the blog-post requested, but the blog owner did not seem to have time to address it.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a Marquee class myself with two inline-block divs. A timer sets the X of the divs one step at a time.